# Can a non-ASCII character be used as a delimiter with Python 2's csv module?

Tags: csv, python-2.7, utf-8

I have some code that works in Python 3, but I need to downgrade it to Python 2. I have a class that writes a csv showing what random strings of ASCII have been generated. Here's the working Python 3 code.

```
file = open(output_table, 'w')
header = 'Path Type Original Attempt Attempt_Length Final Time_1 Time_2 Time_3'.split()
filewriter = csv.writer(self.file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter='ę', quotechar='æ')
```

The issue is that if I use a ascii character, I have a chance of the column's getting off and my script blowing up. How can I delimit columns with a Unicode/UTF-8 character?

Edit:
So I found a few ways to make Python 2 work with utf-8 better. Including

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals
```

at the top of file helped. I'm still getting a TypeError: "delimiter" must be an 1-character string though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you cannot use a multibyte character for the delimiter nor the quotechar in python 2.x:

```
TypeError: "delimiter" must be an 1-character string
```

The error message does say "1-character" and not "1-byte", but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I'd upvote you if I could--I'm thinking now it has something to do with encoding and the fact that Python 2 can't handle unicode for keyword args.

Answer (score -2):

With some fixes to your code, a quick test shows that it works fine.

```
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'wt', newline='') as csvfile:
    header = 'int double str'.split()
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter='ę', quotechar='æ')

    for x in range(5):
        filewriter.writerow((x, x*2, ("fooę "*x)))


with open('output.csv', 'rt') as csvfile:
    filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter='ę', quotechar='æ')

    [print(x) for x in filereader]
```

Output:

```
['0', '0', '']
['1', '2', 'fooę ']
['2', '4', 'fooę fooę ']
['3', '6', 'fooę fooę fooę ']
['4', '8', 'fooę fooę fooę fooę ']
```

Resulting file:

```
æ0æęæ0æęææ
æ1æęæ2æęæfooę æ
æ2æęæ4æęæfooę fooę æ
æ3æęæ6æęæfooę fooę fooę æ
æ4æęæ8æęæfooę fooę fooę fooę æ
```

Comment: Your code has 3 errors.  You seem to be converting the op's code from python 3 to python 3.